# Visual Studio Code - C# formatter - not using [csharp] settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, formatting

I try to format C# code using CTRL+ALT+P or ALT+SHIFT+F

vs code always ask for default formatter and it does not turn tabs to 3 chars as specified in my config

```
"[csharp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "csharpier.csharpier-vscode",
    "editor.tabSize": 3,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 160
},
```

what am I missing here ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

[Document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/formatting-linting) has shown how to set the formatter in vscode for C#.

You can format your C# source code using the [C# Dev Kit extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csdevkit).

Navigate to **File > Preferences > Settings** (Ctrl+,) to customize how your `.cs` files are formatted. The Settings editor gives you a list of different formatting options (particularly under **Commonly Used** and **Text Editor**) that you can adjust across your specific workspace or your entire user profile.

In settings, you can change the tab size to 3.

[image]